# After Updating my msys2 packages my clion dosent detect the mingw installation

Tags: clion, msys2

[clion Toolchain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdBtD.png)
Hello, I am using msys2-mingw64 with clion for a while now, and it worked perfectly fine.
It stopped working after i updated today.
I did pacman -Syu (x2) cause it updated base and restarted and pacman - Su

i guess i could use the bundled one or the msys2 clang stuff, but i had some library installed in mingw-w64 that i am using. Any help is much appreciated. I did reinstalled msys2 but that didnt help with anything.
[my current installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ckxq.png)

Comment: Maybe it needs an extra `\bin` at the end?

Comment: i tried it, but that wont work either. Before the update this was the path i used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71195172/clion-cannot-find-mingw).