# Clion cannot find MinGW

Tags: mingw, clion, mingw-w64, msys2

Clion just cannot find MinGW even I properly set right path.
Someone ask me to post image of C:\msys64 folder.
It used to work fine. But at some point it didn't work. Maybe after I upgraded MinGW or Clion.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you install MSYS2 and install at least one mingw-w64-x86_64 package? Otherwise that folder might not exist.  Please post a screenshot of what Windows Explorer shows for C:\msys64\ so we can see what folders you have there.

Comment: Clion can detect make, gcc, g++. But still told me can't find MinGW

Comment: @DavidGrayson here you go. I swear I install msys2 properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a temporary fix available for mingw-w64-i686-gcc, mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc, mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc 11.2.0-9: See [this youtrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-28403#focus=Comments-27-5803859.0-0).

> FYI, it is possible to workaround the problem with
>
> cd msys[2,64]/[ucrt64|mingw64]/x86_64-w64-mingw32
>
> cd msys[2,64]/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32
>
> mklink /D include ../include

Modified Quote from
Arnaud Dovi