# CLion Custom toolchain can't find MinGW from msys2

Tags: mingw, clion, msys2

I recently installed the 64 bit MinGW toolchain from MSYS2 and have added it to my windows system PATH.

[windows terminal g++ version check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxIvc.png)

However, when I try to add it to Clion, it says that it can't find it even though I have specified the correct path.

[clion toolchain configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsAoR.png)

Does anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71195172/1983398)?

Comment: Yeah, why are you posting the same question as two different users?

Comment: @DavidGrayson I didn't know that this question was asked an hour before I posted mine. And I am not the same person as him.

Comment: It seems we have same problem here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is a temporary fix available for mingw-w64-i686-gcc,
> mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc, mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc 11.2.0-9: See this
> youtrack issue.
>
> ```
> FYI, it is possible to workaround the problem with
>
> cd msys[2,64]/[ucrt64|mingw64]/x86_64-w64-mingw32
>
> cd msys[2,64]/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32
>
> mklink /D include ../include
> ```
>
> Modified Quote from Arnaud Dovi

from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71218465/12557703